# CSS for a 'contact sheet' view that wraps horizontally using a <ul>

Tags: list, css

I'm trying to generate an HTML/CSS combination to display a contact sheet type view of a bunch of photos, each with some text and a form element or two. I'd like the view to fill available width and wrap as needed, in order to get as many images on screen as the user's display can manage. I think a 'ul' is the right container to use, with display set to inline, and I think it's OK to use tables for each of the elements. What I've got so far looks promising in Safari (images that are under-size in either dimension are centered within their cell, wrapping behaves as intended), but fails in FireFox. It also fails the w3c validator (no doctype), but as soon as I specify a doctype the layout breaks (list goes back to displaying in a single column in both browsers).

This is what I have so far:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Layout test</title>
        <style type="text/css">

        #contact_sheet li {
            list-style-type:    none;
            display:        inline;
            text-align:     center;
        }
        #contact_sheet li table {
            width:          auto;
            border-spacing: 0px;
            display:        inline;
            border:         thin solid #202020;
            background-color:   #404040;
            color:          white;
        }
        #contact_sheet li th {
            height:         250px;
            width:          250px;
            text-align:     center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        #contact_sheet li td {
            text-align:     center;
        }
        th img {
            border:         thin solid green;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <ul id="contact_sheet">
            <li>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th><img src="" width="240" height="120" /></th>
                    </tr>    
                    <tr>
                        <td>Some text</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" />Select</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </li>
            <li>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th><img src="" width="120" height="240" /></th>
                    </tr>    
                    <tr>
                        <td>Some text</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" />Select</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </li>
            <li>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th><img src="" width="120" height="120" /></th>
                    </tr>    
                    <tr>
                        <td>Some text</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" />Select</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I migrated this for you since the webapps site is about using webapps, not developing them.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because when the specific doctype, tables took up the entire width of the page.

Just make them float:left and it will work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Layout test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #contact_sheet li {
        list-style-type:    none;
        display:        inline;
        text-align:     center;
    }
    #contact_sheet li table {
        width:          auto;
        border-spacing: 0px;
        display:        inline;
        border:         thin solid #202020;
        background-color:   #404040;
        color:          white;
    }
    #contact_sheet li th {
        height:         250px;
        width:          250px;
        text-align:     center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    #contact_sheet li td {
        text-align:     center;
    }
    table {
        float: left;
    }
    th img {
        border:         thin solid green;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="contact_sheet">
        <li>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th><img src="" width="240" alt="" height="120" /></th>
                </tr>    
                <tr>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" />Select</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </li>
        <li>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th><img src="" width="120" alt="" height="240" /></th>
                </tr>    
                <tr>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" />Select</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </li>
        <li>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th><img src="" width="120" alt="" height="120" /></th>
                </tr>    
                <tr>
                    <td>Some text</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" />Select</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </li>
    </ul>

</body>
```

Comment: Looks good so far, thanks. I'm not sure whether the float will have any adverse effects once this view is put into a page with more content (sorry, bit of a novice here).

Comment: Now that the tables are floated, they don't contribute to the height of the 'ul', so any content placed after that actually gets rendered in the first available space to the right (which might be on the first row or on the first incomplete row depending on the current browser width).

Comment: You can use "overflow:hidden" in the ul to avoid this

Answer (score 1):

Tables are at their best when the width can be predetermined.  You may be better off without tables for your desired effect.  I would suggest simply wrapping each img in a div.  Float all the divs left and you're done.  You then eliminate the need to specify new table rows, as each new row will be created when the floated divs wrap.

That also may make it easier to apply class styles to each individual image/form.

The main problem with this approach which may make it unworkable is that your images are of indeterminate size.  One div would not affect the width of the div below it, leaving you without the order of a grid

Comment: The images are pre-generated thumbnails constrained to a maximum of 240x240 (but maintaining original aspect ratio). I did start off with a table-less approach but failed to get the desired behaviour. As with the previous answer, I expect float:left to cause me issues with positioning of further content.

Comment: Remember: If you add ` overflow: auto ` to the floated element's parent, it eliminates almost all float problems.